# How to add a column with values based on popularity?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following table has Employee and Salary in no particular order. I'm trying to get an output where the top 30% gets a value "high" the next 40% gets "average" and the rest gets "low"

```
Employee  Salary
Tony      50000
Alan      45000
Lee       60000
David     35000
Steve     65000
Paul      48000
Micky     62000
George    80000
Nigel     64000
John      42000
```

Output:

```
Employee   Salary   Percentage
Tony       50000    Average
Alan       45000    Low
Lee        60000    Average
David      35000    Low
Steve      65000    High
Paul       48000    Average
Micky      62000    Average
George     80000    High
Nigel      64000    High
John       42000    Low
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by using the `Window` function `percent_rank`. However, it requires sorting the dataframe after the Salary column. The `percent_rank` function will give each row a percent value depending on the sorted order, more specifically, the value given is:

> (rank of row in its partition - 1) / (number of rows in the partition - 1)

Assuming the original dataframe is `df`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Percentage", percent_rank over Window.orderBy("Salary"))
  .withColumn("Percentage", when($"Percentage" > 0.7, "High").
                            when($"Percentage" < 0.3, "Low").
                            otherwise("Average"))
```

The result using the data in the question will be:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|Employee|Salary|Percentage|
+--------+------+----------+
|   David| 35000|       Low|
|    John| 42000|       Low|
|    Alan| 45000|       Low|
|    Paul| 48000|   Average|
|    Tony| 50000|   Average|
|     Lee| 60000|   Average|
|   Micky| 62000|   Average|
|   Nigel| 64000|      High|
|   Steve| 65000|      High|
|  George| 80000|      High|
+--------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement it as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.percent_rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

 dataDF.show
+--------+------+
|Employee|Salary|
+--------+------+
|    Tony| 50000|
|    Alan| 45000|
|     Lee| 60000|
|   David| 35000|
|   Steve| 65000|
|    Paul| 48000|
|   Micky| 62000|
|  George| 80000|
|   Nigel| 64000|
|    John| 42000|
+--------+------+

val window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(dataDF("Salary"))
dataDF.withColumn("rank", 
percent_rank().over(window).alias("rank")).withColumn("Percentage", 
when($"rank" > 0.7, "High").when($"rank" <= 0.7 && $"rank" > 0.3, 
"Average").otherwise("Low")).drop("rank").show

+--------+------+----------+
|Employee|Salary|Percentage|
+--------+------+----------+
|   David| 35000|       Low|
|    John| 42000|       Low|
|    Alan| 45000|       Low|
|    Paul| 48000|   Average|
|    Tony| 50000|   Average|
|     Lee| 60000|   Average|
|   Micky| 62000|   Average|
|   Nigel| 64000|      High|
|   Steve| 65000|      High|
|  George| 80000|      High|
+--------+------+----------+
```